# Why is SPOOL writing my output with LINESIZE set to 32767?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to spool certain data, but for some reason it gets wrapped to the next line.

This is the script I am using to SPOOL (I am adding the full script with comments in case it has any significance)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED SIZE UNLIMITED
SET LONG 2000000000
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET TRIMSPOOL ON

/* -------------------------------------------------- COMMENT --------------------------------------------------
COMMENT1
COMMENT2
COMMENT3
COMMENT4
COMMENT5
*/
SPOOL "File_Name_MySYNONYM_SCRIPT-11111111.sql"
  select SCRIPT FROM MY_TABLE_2_UPDATE  where OBJECT_ID =11111;
SPOOL OFF
```

SCRIPT is a CLOB column and for the given ID contains:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM "MY_SYNONYM_12345" FOR "MS1"."MY_OBJECT1_SETUP";
```

This is the Output I get in the spooled file:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM "MY_SYNONYM_12345" FOR "MS1"."MY_OBJECT1_SETU
P";
```

You can see the **P";** gets wrapped to the second line. The line is actually wrapped, it is not my editor (Notepad++) that is showing it wrong, I have "Word Wrap" deactivated.

I don't know what other  SQL PLUS parameter I need to set to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line

Comment: where is create statement ?

Comment: @jWeaver - Sorry but I don't understand your question? That create statement is the spool output, saved in the "File_Name_MySYNONYM_SCRIPT-11111111.sql" file. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @Rene - The issue is not in my Viewer, the scripts are actually wrapped, it has a new line after "SETU". You can see the "------COMMENT---" line I have is longer than the output, and it doesn't get wrapped.

Comment: Dumb question, maybe, but does the script column you're selecting contain the newline?

Comment: @Boneist - Nope, that line is actually generated with DBMS_METADATA.GET_DLL, and if I use DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE to spool it, instead of the select you see in my question, it doesn't get the New Line in the middle. I would switch to DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE right now, if it were not I am having issues when the SCRIPT returned is larger than 32767 chars :(

Comment: Try adding this after the SET command and before the SPOOL: "COLUMN SCRIPT FORM A3000". If sqlplus defaults the column SCRIPT to say 80 it will wrap.

Comment: Have you tried : set wrap off ?

Comment: @Rene - Yes, I have tried that. When I set it bellow all the other SET the spooled file is empty.

Comment: @TenG - After doing some thorough testing setting "COLUMN SCRIPT FORM A3000" works! However I noticed that I get some New Lines I can't get rid off. Originally the scripts had only 1 New Line before the text and a New Line after it, after the change I have 1 new Line before the Text and 3 after it, could this setting be affecting the New Lines? In any case your suggestion solves my issue, if you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @TenG - I can't find documentation for "COLUMN SCRIPT FORM A300", could you, maybe, provide a link?

Comment: The command is COLUMN, followed by the column name, then the formatting. In this case we are telling sqlplus to uses a 3000 character length field for the display of column named SCRIPT. See "Formatting Columns" section here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer as it seemed to help.

Try adding this after the SET command and before the SPOOL: "COLUMN SCRIPT FORM A3000". If sqlplus defaults the column SCRIPT to say 80 it will wrap.

However, reading further it seems you have other formatting issues, and also it seems the data is from  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DLL.

I have written many tools (going back to v7) to extract DDL to scripts so that schemas can be rebuilt, and although  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL is a huge help I still find it doesn't quite do the whole thing as neatly as you would like. So be warned. My scripts combine GET_DDL and some custom extract queries to get the nice clean usable scripts.

To remove extraneous line feeds, try this is your session:

```
exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'PRETTY',false);
```

Documentation for this is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#BGBJBFGE)

Comment: Yes you are tight my query comes from DMBS.GET_DDL. What do you mean by Custom extract queries?

Comment: @Dzyann - What I mean by custom extract queries is that rather than using GEL_DDL I write my own SQL to get the DDL directly from DBA_SOURCE, DBA_TRIGGERS etc where GET_DDL does not quite work as I want. For example, with PLSQL code, I found that the codebase had odd code (caused by TOAD devotees and their mongrel code formatting) which confounded GET_DDL, so I queried DBA_SOURCE direct.  Synonyms and grants had to be extracted directly to ensure the scripts were complete.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am still new with all these things of Oracle. Thanks for the advise. So far I have been lucky and the only issue I have encountered is the additional spaces.